# BIOS wont boot (code 66) when Sata drive connected

Tags: boot, bios, sata, hardware-failure

When I can to one of my computers today it was showing Intel's splash screen (two intel logos, BIOS Settings: '<kbd>F2</kbd>' and '66'.

The board is an intel dp55wb.

Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> does nothing.

However, when I disconnect my internal Samsung HD103SJ 1T HD (SATA - or is it SATA2 - I am not sure) it does respond to the <kbd>F2</kbd> key.

Any idea on what I should/can do?
Does this mean that the drive is gone?

Comment: Some good news,
I disconnected my SATA DVD and used its cable to connect the HD and it booted properly.
So now how do I know it the fault is with the Cable? the DVD? the SATA port on the board?

Comment: Good news, I disconnected my SATA DVD (DVD side) and plugged its cable to the HD and the machine now boots OK.
Next thing would be to try a new cable to connect the DVD. 
Are there any tools that test SATA cables?

Comment: It sounds like the SATA controller you were using failed.  Test this theory by connecting it to your DVD drive.