# Intel DP55WG motherboard stuck in POST (code 65/66)

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios, uefi

After installing Windows 10, my Intel DP55WG motherboard gets stuck in its POST for over a minute. During that time,

[image]

- It displays a static image containing two Intel logos, keys to press for BIOS/boot menu/… and the number 66 in the bottom right of the screen. This number changes during the entire boot sequence, even when Windows is loading. (But while stuck, always 66.)
- The computer doesn’t respond to any input, including said keys. But when unstuck, will enter BIOS if the corresponding key has been pressed while stuck.
- The HDD led is lit almost non-stop

Then suddenly, the HDD led goes back to its occasional blinking, (if no key has been pressed) Windows loads as it should and the number changes to several values (E7, 94, …) before disappearing at the Windows login screen.

I have never had any problems with the exact same hardware configuration running Windows 7 Enterprise. (Booted from GRUB to be fair, as it was a dual boot setup.) The SSD I’m booting from is a Samsung Evo 840 which, according to SMART, is tiptop. Hasn’t given me any trouble so far and works fine in Windows.

(Side note: I first installed Windows 10 on an MBR disk+UEFI disabled. Which has worked on many computers before, but on this one didn’t get me more than an underscore in the top left corner of a black screen, not even blinking as it should. Thanks to a peculiar 'back to bios' physical button I was able to switch to UEFI+GPT, reinstalled and ran into my current problem.)

66 is most likely a POST code but for the life of me I haven’t been able to find its meaning.

Full Windows version = Windows 10 Enterprise N 2016 LTSB. (Installed successfully on dozens of computers.)

BIOS option ‘HDD pre-delay’=0.

I have tried:

- Disabling Windows fast startup, so shutdown results in a proper
  cold start. (Control panel > power plan > power button settings)
- Disabling the “hide POST text” option to try and learn more, but 
  that doesn’t make any difference.
- Messing around with the boot priority and disabling all irrelevant 
  devices as a boot option (optic, USB, network, …). When looking at 
  the boot options, the BIOS claims no device is connected to 3 out of 
  6 SATA ports, while all of them have HDD/SSD’s, which work fine in
  Windows. (AHCI enabled)

All to no avail, obviously. Can anyone solve this mystery? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I tried booting with several HDD disconnected. To clarify, I have

- 1 SSD (booting Windows, GPT, multiple partitions)
- 3 HDD < 2TB (MBR, 2x single partition, 1x multiple partitions)
- 1 HDD > 2TB (GPT, single partition) (HGST Deskstar NAS 4TB)
- 1 Empty hot swap drive for 3.5" HDD's.

Below are the times each tested combination of HDD/SSD caused the PC to stay in the "BIOS 66" screen.

- All but SSD **dis**connected: 3 seconds
- All but HGST connected: 18 seconds
- All but HGST and swap connected: 18 seconds
- All but the 3 HDD < 2TB connected: 53 seconds
- All connected: 68 seconds

So I conclude:

- The more HDD's are connected, the slower POST 66 gets.
- The main culprit seems to be the HGST, the only drive > 2TB. Should be irrelevant, but that's the only thing it doesn't have in
  common with any other drive (that I can see).
- The hot swap drive (empty) is above suspicion.

I keep wondering why this problem did not occur with the exact same hardware when my SSD had a GRUB bootloader instead of Windows 10. Should be irrelevant since we're in POST, but that is all that has changed!

Comment: Similar question here>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/400988/bios-wont-boot-code-66-when-sata-drive-connected

Comment: Be sure hard drive is connected to Sata 0 (or 1 of no 0) port on the motherboard.

Comment: Hi @Moab, I connected the Windows SSD to port 0 (which was not the case before) but that made no difference. I did do some experimenting with sata connections and will be editing my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final episode of this saga, as I finally got it to work properly. Sharing because I haven’t found a solution online, but did learn I'm far from the only one who ran into problems with these peculiar old Intel motherboards.

(Just to scratch the itch I had about GRUB, I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows, but that of course didn't help. Hey, everyone is entitled to a Hail Mary.)

I updated my BIOS firmware to the latest I could find. Was on 4507, upgraded to 5936. (BIOS ‘Main’ tab > the four numbers after 86A or 86I is your current version.)
Intel discontinued support for these motherboards, which apparently means even the drivers and updates had to be taken offline. I was reluctant to download drivers from a third-party site, which is why I put it off for as long as I did. But as I was running out of options I downloaded an update [here](https://rebyte.me/en/intel/1143/?fileTypeId=4).
I used the F7 method (.bio file on a thumb drive). Details [here](https://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/support/articles/000005724/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html).

Result: same problem, different code. (65 instead of 66) Got some new peculiar fast boot options, none of which helped. Also, BIOS was still not detecting all HDD’s correctly.

So I decided to give legacy (UEFI disabled) another go on the new firmware. Wiped SSD and converted to MBR once more. Reinstalled Windows and finally got a reasonable boot time. Also, BIOS is now able to properly identify all installed HDD’s.

In conclusion, the solution was updating BIOS and disabling UEFI boot. I’ve worked with quite a few motherboards and have never encountered a more peculiar and buggy one than the DP55WG. I understand why Intel wants to distance itself from this generation of motherboards. Especially UEFI mode is a train wreck, steer clear of it. Hope this helps someone.